# How do I interpret this template signature of priority queue?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <class T, class Container = vector<T>, class Compare = less<typename Container::value_type> > class priority_queue;
```

I understand the first two template arguments, the first template argument is the data type of the element being stored in the priority queue and the second one is the kind of container that the programmer wants to use, it could be either deque or vector.

But the third argument confuses me a bit, because I have never seen something like it. I'd have done something like:

```
template <class T, class Container = vector<T>
class priority_queue{
    /* Implementation */
};
```

Does it have something to do with the strict weak ordering criterion necessary for priority queue? If yes, how can I learn more about it? Could you give an example of using the third argument?

I am new to template programming, so I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: It's specifying how you want to compare the things in the queue, to work out their priority. By default it's going to use std::less.

Comment: First and second and third argument are essentially the same - what exactly don't you understand? Since you've obviously searched for something like https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+priority_queue+what+is+compare+for you've already seen examples of usage - not sure why you ask for it in the post...

Comment: @Alexei The same how?

Comment: @latedeveloper the question (see title) is mostly about reading the signature - so both second and third arguments are of the same format - `class c = type<other_type>`. I assume OP already read documentation and knows what `Compare` is for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter specifies the comparator class.

The comparator class is responsible for comparing queue elements, in order to determine the queue order. You already understand that the elements in the queue are ordered with the "higher" values first. Well, this is what defines what "higher" means, here.

The comparator class has a simple interface: given two values, return `true` if the first value is less than the second value, and `false` otherwise. The default implementation, `std::less`, uses the traditional `<` operator to compare the two values.

Use a custom comparator class in order to change the behavior of the priority queue. One example would be to specify `std::greater` instead of `std::less` as the comparator class. `std::greater` uses the `>` operator, so this creates a priority queue "in opposite order", which gives you the lowest values first, rather than highest one.

Or, you could create your own custom comparator class, such as:

```
class last_four_bits {

public:

    bool operator()(int a, int b) const
    {
           return (a & 0x0F) < (b & 0x0F);
    }
};
```

This comparator class compares the least four bits of an `int` only. This, in turn, makes this:

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, last_four_bits>
```

look at the least four bits of each `int` value in the queue, thus ordering all `int`s with the highest values in the last four bits before the ones with the lesser values, ignoring all other bits in the `int`.

P.S. Comparator classes are also used with associative containers, `set`s and `map`s, and serve the same function there. By carefully crafting a comparator class you can create sets and maps whose iterators iterate over the keys in the set/map in some order other than the lowest to the highest keys (as you understand "lowest" and "highest" to mean, intrinsically).